# C Program just freeze when I use scanf in a loop

Tags: c, algorithm

I am writing a simple algorithm for a question on coursera and while I start entering values through scanf(), my program is just freezing. It's not executing and even existing the loop. When it didn't work in my laptop, I tried it in an online compiler and it didn't work there also. I was facing the same problem with a similar algorithm question of Coursera.

P.S. The complete code was needed to answer the question.

```
    int main()
    {
        int distance;
        scanf("%d", &distance);
        int range;
        scanf("%d", &range);
        int pumps;
        scanf("%d", &pumps);
        int disPump[pumps];
        for(int i = 0; i < pumps; i++){
            scanf("%d", &disPump[i]);
        }
        //Program is never reaching this line and is just freezing
        printf("Loop terminated."); 
        int minRefuel = calcRefuel(distance, range, disPump, pumps);
    }

int calcRefuel(int distance, int range, int disPump[], int pumps){
    
    // Array will be sorted here in ascending order using bubble sort.
    for(int i = 0; i < pumps - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < pumps - i - 1; j++){
            if(disPump[j] > disPump[j+1]){
                int temp = disPump[j];
                disPump[j] = disPump[j+1];
                disPump[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // main algorithm starts here.
    int distCovered = 0;
    int refill = 0;
    while(1){
        int nearestPump = locatePump(range, disPump, pumps, distCovered);
        distCovered += nearestPump;
        refill++;
        if((distCovered+range) >= distance){
            break;
        }
    }
    return refill;
}

int locatePump(int range, int disPump[], int pumps, int distCovered){
    range += distCovered;
    int i = 0;
    // Doubt about while.
    while(range >= disPump[i] && range < disPump[i+1]){
        i++;
    }
    return disPump[i] - distCovered;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the input?

Comment: "950 400 4 200 375 550 750"

Comment: Probably stuck in `calcRefuel` and not flushing the previous output. Post [mcve].

Comment: Also you should check `scanf` return values to make sure the input was taken.

Comment: After entering a number, I am pressing enter key to enter the next. This input is from the question on algorithm.

Comment: Try `printf("output with no newline"); fflush(stdout);` or, maybe simpler: `printf("outout with newline\n");`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have printed a loop terminated statement and it never got printed. That means it never reached the function calcRefuel.

Comment: Tell what platform/compiler/ide/os you use.

Comment: "That means it never reached the function calcRefuel."  Not necessarily, it could mean that the print output has not yet flushed and the program is hanging in `calcRefuel`.  Try echoing back the inputs after you read them, to confirm that the program is seeing what you think you're giving it.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code with default compiler in macOS BigSur 11.6

Comment: @pjs could you please attach some references? I didn't understand what you are saying.

Comment: `fflush(stdout)` to allow `printf`to be used for debugging.

Comment: I'm also using Big Sur, and after adding `#include <stdio.h>` and commenting out the call to `calcRefuel` (which you didn't supply), the program prints the "Loop terminated" statement.  I cannot reproduce your problem, voting to close.

Comment: change `printf("Loop terminated.");` --> `printf("Loop terminated.\n");` (addition of the `\n`), now do you see the "Loop terminated" output?

Comment: Re the code edit: your functions have no function declarations above `main()`, and you have no library header `#include`s.

Comment: You have at least one potentially non-terminating loop. Focus on it.

Comment: ...and `// Doubt about while` potentially array-breaking indexing.

Comment: @pjs could you give it one more shot? I have added the remaining code and you have closed my question, afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't any syntax error or logical error as people were telling. It was just some compiler related issue. I tried coding the same thing in a different laptop and it was working. The reason I posted this was because it didn't even worked in the online compiler maybe it was a coincident. So, I thought there is something that I don't know and posted it here.

Comment: Some online compilers don't allow you to run the program interactively, which means that you need to specify all of the the input of the program (stdin) before running the program.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in the online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBifz.png)You need to start your program in a terminal and put values in.

Comment: It's not working for me. Can other functions used affect the code in anyway? Maybe when the compiler is compiling the entire code and producing that executable file, there are some anomalies happening that is hindering inputs.

Comment: My guess is you said it freezes. It dont crash so its waiting for your input. I think you are using an env that don`t have the input stream activated, like cout is not working with the qt debugger. Try open it in another terminal and put some comments when which scan f is called.

Comment: @Dirghayu other functions can affect the `main()` code. Undefined behaviour may result in all kinds of unspecified damage, or none.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you stated that your program was freezing without reaching the end of the loop.

In your self-answer, you stated further that the program worked when you instead tested it on your laptop.

My guess is that you got confused what was going on in the program, because your program does not provide any feedback. It never prints any messages prompting the user for any input, so you have no idea in what state the program currently is and which input the program is expecting next. This can cause the false impression that your program is "frozen". I suggest that you add a few `printf` statements to your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int distance;
    printf( "Please enter the distance: \n" );
    scanf("%d", &distance);

    int range;
    printf( "Please enter the range: " );
    scanf("%d", &range);

    int pumps;
    printf( "Please enter the number of pumps: " );
    scanf("%d", &pumps);

    int disPump[pumps];
    for(int i = 0; i < pumps; i++){
        printf( "Please enter the number for pump #%d: ", i + 1 );
        scanf("%d", &disPump[i]);
    }
    printf("Loop terminated.");
    int minRefuel = calcRefuel(distance, range, disPump, pumps);
}
```

That way, you should always know in what state the program currently is and which input the program is expecting next.

However, this approach does still have one problem. As already pointed out in the comments section, if your program gets stuck in an infinite loop, then you may not see the latest `printf` statements on the screen. This is because `stdout` is buffered and the output may have not yet been flushed out of the buffer.

For this reason, it is possible that the output of the line

`printf("Loop terminated.");`

is not being displayed, if your program somehow gets stuck inside the function `calcRefuel`.

Since `stdout` is normally line-buffered when writing to a terminal, the simplest fix would be to add a new line character, like this:

`printf("Loop terminated.\n");`

You can also explicitly flush the buffer of `stdout` using:

`fflush( stdout );`

An alternative would be to print to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, which is unbuffered. You can accomplish this by using `fprintf` instead of `printf`.